# Cognos Single Report, Multiple CSV Pages to Single Email

Tags: cognos

Wonder if someone can assist me?

I have a report with 4 pages that I want to schedule to email, but I want to have the for reports attached as 4 separate .csv files to the email. 
Is that possible? If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you 
(Cognos Analytics 11.0.9 - Soon to be 11.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV output is a simple data dump.  You need separate reports and separate schedules = separate emails.  If CSV output is the goal, your output should be a single page containing a single list.  No headers, footers, totals, subtotals, text descriptions outside the list.  Definitely no crosstabs or charts.  Just a list.

Running a report to CSV will return a single file containing a single data set.  If you have multiple pages, or even just multiple data presentation objects (lists, crosstabs, etc.) on a single-page report, you'll get the CSV from the first query (not presentation object) that Cognos decides is the one it thinks you want.

Here's an example:

Create a report that contains (from top to bottom) a header, a singleton sourced from one of the columns in a query that contains 3 output columns, a (empty) block, and a list sourced from a second query.  Run it to HTML, then run it to CSV.  The CSV output will probably be the output from the query behind the singleton -- so it will not look like anything you saw on the HTML output.

If you really think you need CSV, you're probably using the wrong tool.  Cognos is a reporting and dashboarding tool.  CSV is for data distribution, sharing, or migration.  It's useful for machines to consume, but not for humans to consume.  You probably need an ETL tool.